# Reload jQuery tab's content dynamically

Tags: jquery

In my jQuery tabs I had to implement pagination functionality, so I did dynamic reload tab's content with the code:

```
$('#articles_tabs').tabs('url', index, url).tabs('load', index);
```

but since 1.9.0 `url` method has been deprecated and the code above doesn't work anymore...

Does anybody know how to rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery [site](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/):

> The content for each tab panel can be defined in-page or can be loaded via Ajax; both are handled automatically based on the href of the anchor associated with the tab.

In other words just put you content location in the `href` attribute. You can force loading by calling `$('#articles_tabs').tabs( "load", 1 );`